# Not changing image src attribute through javascript

Tags: javascript

The following is my current JavaScript code which is not working. I'm trying to change the image.

```
function imgchange(a)
{
    var e=document.getElementById(a);

     if(e.src == "plus.png")
     {
       e.src = "minus.png";
     }

     else
    {
      e.src="plus.png";
     }

}
```

Comment: How do you attach the event? Show the html

Comment: Please add the HTML and more information, like what doesn't work to your answer using the edit button.

Comment: Post your code.. In general It looks ok

Comment: Just a note, use === for type safe evaluation!

Comment: @BrentEchols `src` only returns a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) though.

Answer (score 1):

`src` property includes the full url of the image, try using `getAttribute` method, which returns the specified value in the HTML.

```
if ( e.getAttribute("src") === "plus.png" )
```

Note that means that you should also set the new value using `.setAttribute()` for future comparisons. If you want to use the `.src` property you should either compare the full paths or use other methods like regular expression or `split` method:

```
if ( e.src.split('/').pop() === "plus.png" )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `img.src` it returns whole path to img src, not only `plus.png`

You have to make comparison like `http://localhost/images/plus.png` (**whatever your path is**)

or use `getAttribute` method like is mentioned in undefined's post

Answer (score 0):

the function itself should be working. there must be something wrong at the place you are calling `imgchange("xyz")`.

so maybe you can show us the code where the function is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

```
function imgchange (a) {
    var e=document.getElementById(a);
    if (e.src.replace(/.+\//, '') === 'plus.png') {
        e.src = "minus.png";
    } else {
        e.src="plus.png";
    }
}
```

Should work.